# Shell Script for GIT commands

Tags: git, shell

I have a requirement to merge/rebase the feature branch to develop branch using git commands in shell script.Can anyone please tell me the command which will merge/rebase the feature branch X to the develop branch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see how your question is shell-related, but if you are on *develop*, the command

```
 git merge feature/xxxxxx
```

should do what you want to achieve.